# PHP: No link in title of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my home page on this webpage: http://goodbyeboringlife.com/ to display my latest blog posts of whatever category.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
'posts-per-page' => 10,
'cat'      => 11,
'order'    => 'DESC'
);
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo "<div class='post-loop-image'>";
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<span class='post_title'>" . the_title() . "</span>";
     endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

It looks how I want it, and I will tweak it more with CSS later, but the code is missing link to the actual post. I have no idea how to implement that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
'posts-per-page' => 10,
'cat'      => 11,
'order'    => 'DESC'
);
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo "<div class='post-loop-image'>";
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<a href='".the_permalink()."'"> <span class='post_title'>" . the_title() . "</span></a>";
     endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

This will generate a link on your post title

Comment: Where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the titles' code block with this:

```
echo "<a href='" . the_permalink() . "'"> <span class='post_title'>" . the_title() . "</span></a>";
```

the_permalink() is a WordPress built in function that retrieves the posts link